# Why $\ x^n - 1$ is separable if gcd(p,n) = 1?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, prime-numbers, cyclotomic-polynomials

When I'm reading the proof of theorem 5.4. In the context, it states that $\ T^n -1$ is separable in $\ F_n [T]$ (Here we need (p,n) = 1)

http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/cyclotomic.pdf

Comment: look at the formal derivative

Comment: So, you mean gcd($\ nT^n,\ T^n - 1$) = 1 in $\ F_n[x]$ if and only if $\ T^n - 1$ is separable

Comment: yes since formal derivative is  zero only at multiple roots

Comment: And, it is true since $\ \bar n\  \neq 0$(mod p)

Comment: @AsharTafhim Thanks!!